# Container managed Transaction for JPA+Spring+Hibernate in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa-2.0

I am trying to configure JOTM with JPA,Spring, hibernate and tomcat. I have configured somehow but neither it perform inserts nor updates, in other words, i am unable to perform commits after inserting/updating data. I have following configuration.

**%TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resource name="jdbc/myDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.XADataSource" factory="org.objectweb.jotm.datasource.DataSourceFactory" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" username="root" password="mypassword" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB"/>
    <Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction"/>
    <Transaction factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="60"/>
</Context>
```

**JOTM 2.1.9 libaries extracted in %TOMCAT%/lib**

```
          Jotm-datasource.jar
·         Jotm-core.jar
·         Xapool.jar
·         Log4j.jar
·         Commons-loggin-api.jar
·         Carol-iiop-delegate.jar
·         Carol-interceptors.jar
·         Carol.jar
·         Ow2-jta-1.1-spec.jar
·         Ow2-connector-1.5-spec.jar
·         Howl.jar
```

**src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml**

```
<Context path="/MyJPATest" reloadable="true">
    <Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
</Context>
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/carol.properties**

```
# JNDI (Protocol Invocation)

carol.protocols=jrmp

# Local RMI Invocation
carol.jvm.rmi.local.call=true


# do not use CAROL JNDI wrapper
carol.start.jndi=false

# do not start a name server
carol.start.ns=false

# Naming Factory
carol.jndi.java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.apache.naming
```

**META-INF/Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/myDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.test.domain.PUser</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
 <bean
        id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property
            name="persistenceUnitName"
            value="myPersistenceUnit" />
    </bean>


    <context:annotation-config />

    <jee:jndi-lookup
        id="jndiUserTransaction"
        jndi-name="java:comp/UserTransaction" />

    <bean
        id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" >

        <property
            name="userTransaction"
            ref="jndiUserTransaction" />
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

      <jpa:repositories
        base-package="com.test"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />



    <bean
        id="hibernate4ExceptionTranslator"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator" />
```

**web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDS</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.XADataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

**PUserService's method**

```
 @Transactional
    public List<PUser> bootstrapUsers( )
    {

        List<PUser> users = new ArrayList<PUser>();

        try
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {

                PUser newUser = new PUser();
                newUser.setName("B_" + i);
                PUser user = this.pUserRepository.save(newUser);


                users.add(user);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.logger.error(e, e);

            return null;
        }

        return users;

    }
```

**src/main/java/com.test.dao.PUserRepository (Spring-data repository)**

```
public interface PUserRepository extends JpaRepository<PUser, Serializable>
{

    PUser findByName(String username);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you call PUserRepository#flush() at the end and print out the stacktrace, if there is no transaction active at this point it should throw an exception. It would give an idea about the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using JTA your transaction-type should be `transaction-type="JTA"` in your persistence.xml. You can read more on this [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html#Configuration%20and%20bootstrapping) under Configuration and bootstrapping.

Comment: your are absolutely right. i should but here i am not using JEE container but servlet container with JOTM support therefore switching to JTA is not acceptable by tomcat. I have successfully configured container managed transaction with JEE container, where i used JTA transaction type but unable to configure it with tomcat.